# sqlite casuing JVM to crash

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using sqlite with java. Code is very basic and includes insertion and select logic. Code was working fine for 6-7 months. But after installing antivirus on one of the machines code started behaving weird. JVM started crashing randomly. A pid_err file is generated every time JVM crashes. I can see that error is related to sqlite dll and coming in  org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8() method. But I cant figure out the reson for the same. Below is one of the place where code breaks:

```
try {
          conn=getConnection();
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM app_config;" );
          while ( rs.next() ) {
             if(STIME_KEY.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(1))){
                 time=rs.getString(2);
             }
          }
          rs.close();
          }
```

Below is pid_err file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000068788029, pid=15888, tid=0x0000000000003ea4
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sqlite-3.19.3-c47d36da-90d9-4b67-b5e8-aaf0f27240d2-sqlitejdbc.dll+0x88029]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: H:\jar\hs_err_pid15888.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000229f800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=16036, stack(0x0000000002a70000,0x0000000002b70000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x0000000000000001

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000001, RBX=0x0000000052c87c58, RCX=0x0000000052c71d4d, RDX=0x0000000000000002
RSP=0x0000000002b6dbf0, RBP=0x000000000016fe48, RSI=0x0000000052c79278, RDI=0x0000000052c70f38
R8 =0x0000000000000001, R9 =0x0000000052c71d48, R10=0x00000000687dab00, R11=0x0000000052c71d48
R12=0x0000000000000001, R13=0x0000000052c73008, R14=0x0000000052c792a8, R15=0x0000000000000001
RIP=0x0000000068788029, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000002b6dbf0)
0x0000000002b6dbf0:   0000000055e39d70 000000000327a660
0x0000000002b6dc00:   0000000002b6dd00 0000000102b6e930
0x0000000002b6dc10:   0000000052c68f08 0000000002b6dcd0
0x0000000002b6dc20:   0000000002b6dcb0 0000000002b6e970
0x0000000002b6dc30:   0000000002b6dca4 0000000002b6eed0
0x0000000002b6dc40:   0000000052c771a8 00000000687ca2f4
0x0000000002b6dc50:   0000000000000000 0000000052c68f08
0x0000000002b6dc60:   0000000052c9ebd8 0000000052c77228
0x0000000002b6dc70:   0000000052c76848 0000000052c79278
0x0000000002b6dc80:   0000000755e39100 0000000700000001
0x0000000002b6dc90:   0000000100000000 0000000052c771b0
0x0000000002b6dca0:   0000000000000000 000000400029f800
0x0000000002b6dcb0:   0000000002b6dcc0 0000000052c79280
0x0000000002b6dcc0:   0000000052c87c58 0000000000000005
0x0000000002b6dcd0:   000000004c4a4980 0000000052c76848
0x0000000002b6dce0:   0000000002b6dd90 0000000002b6ddc0 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000068788029)
0x0000000068788009:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000068788019:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000068788029:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x0000000068788039:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000052c87c58 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000052c71d4d is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000002b6dbf0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000229f800
RBP=0x000000000016fe48 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000052c79278 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000052c70f38 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000052c71d48 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000687dab00 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000052c71d48 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000052c73008 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000052c792a8 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000002a70000,0x0000000002b70000],  sp=0x0000000002b6dbf0,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [sqlite-3.19.3-c47d36da-90d9-4b67-b5e8-aaf0f27240d2-sqlitejdbc.dll+0x88029]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8([B)J+0
j  org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(Ljava/lang/String;)J+5
j  org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(Lorg/sqlite/core/CoreStatement;)V+36
j  org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/ResultSet;+14
j  com.app.db.DBManagement.getLastRunTime()Ljava/lang/String;+29
j  com.app.data.createTouchFile()V+22
j  com.app.data.fetchData([Ljava/lang/String;)V+144
j  com.app.InitiatorDataFetcher.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+160
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000549a4000 JavaThread "Connect thread 10.65.8.46 session" [_thread_in_native, id=9688, stack(0x0000000054530000,0x0000000054630000)]
  0x000000004f28c000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10372, stack(0x0000000053820000,0x0000000053920000)]
  0x000000004f262000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9172, stack(0x00000000535e0000,0x00000000536e0000)]
  0x000000004f259800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16532, stack(0x00000000536e0000,0x00000000537e0000)]
  0x000000004f256800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5420, stack(0x0000000053330000,0x0000000053430000)]
  0x000000004f246000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13504, stack(0x0000000053450000,0x0000000053550000)]
  0x000000004f23b000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9136, stack(0x0000000052f40000,0x0000000053040000)]
  0x000000004f230800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17716, stack(0x0000000053220000,0x0000000053320000)]
  0x000000004f21f000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12184, stack(0x0000000053040000,0x0000000053140000)]
  0x000000004f219800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4440, stack(0x0000000052dd0000,0x0000000052ed0000)]
  0x000000004f210800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8032, stack(0x0000000052b60000,0x0000000052c60000)]
  0x000000004f200000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7512, stack(0x0000000052a40000,0x0000000052b40000)]
  0x000000004f1ea800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7916, stack(0x0000000052930000,0x0000000052a30000)]
  0x000000004f1ba000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8308, stack(0x0000000052750000,0x0000000052850000)]
  0x000000004f195000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8196, stack(0x00000000525c0000,0x00000000526c0000)]
  0x000000004f194000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7344, stack(0x0000000052380000,0x0000000052480000)]
  0x000000004f18e000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4380, stack(0x00000000524a0000,0x00000000525a0000)]
  0x000000004f18b000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13332, stack(0x00000000521d0000,0x00000000522d0000)]
  0x000000004cc1f800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9000, stack(0x0000000051e50000,0x0000000051f50000)]
  0x000000004f17b800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14556, stack(0x0000000052090000,0x0000000052190000)]
  0x000000004f134800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15472, stack(0x0000000051f70000,0x0000000052070000)]
=>0x000000000229f800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=16036, stack(0x0000000002a70000,0x0000000002b70000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000004cc13800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000051cf0000,0x0000000051df0000] [id=7048]
  0x000000004f29f000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000053980000,0x0000000053a80000] [id=16924]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 458752K, used 110108K [0x00000005c0380000, 0x00000005e0380000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 393216K, 28% used [0x00000005c0380000,0x00000005c6f072f0,0x00000005d8380000)
  from space 65536K, 0% used [0x00000005dc380000,0x00000005dc380000,0x00000005e0380000)
  to   space 65536K, 0% used [0x00000005d8380000,0x00000005d8380000,0x00000005dc380000)
 ParOldGen       total 1048576K, used 0K [0x00000001c0a00000, 0x0000000200a00000, 0x00000005c0380000)
  object space 1048576K, 0% used [0x00000001c0a00000,0x00000001c0a00000,0x0000000200a00000)
 Metaspace       used 11828K, capacity 12118K, committed 12544K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1327K, capacity 1413K, committed 1536K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012200000,0x0000000015200000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000113fb000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006377c720
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000019090000, 0x0000000031068000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000031068000, 0x0000000049040000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000170000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=6553Kb max_used=6553Kb free=239206Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002e40000, 0x00000000034b0000, 0x0000000011e40000]
 total_blobs=1640 nmethods=1254 adapters=295
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 8.330 Thread 0x000000004f256800 1250       3       sun.security.provider.MD5::implCompress (1508 bytes)
Event: 8.330 Thread 0x000000004f259800 1251       3       sun.security.provider.ByteArrayAccess::b2iLittle64 (614 bytes)
Event: 8.332 Thread 0x000000004f259800 nmethod 1251 0x000000000349f710 code [0x000000000349f8a0, 0x000000000349fe28]
Event: 8.337 Thread 0x000000004f256800 nmethod 1250 0x00000000034a5710 code [0x00000000034a5aa0, 0x00000000034a81c8]
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000004f23b000 1252       3       java.lang.Character::digit (6 bytes)
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000004f246000 1253       3       java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1::digit (91 bytes)
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000004f262000 1254       3       java.util.Calendar::internalGet (7 bytes)
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000004f23b000 nmethod 1252 0x000000000349f1d0 code [0x000000000349f340, 0x000000000349f5d8]
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000004f262000 nmethod 1254 0x000000000349ee10 code [0x000000000349ef60, 0x000000000349f0d0]
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000004f246000 nmethod 1253 0x000000000349e790 code [0x000000000349e900, 0x000000000349ec90]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 6.638 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000032b9490 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 19
Event: 6.638 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000032b9490 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 19
Event: 6.638 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000032b9490 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 19
Event: 6.638 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000032b9490 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 19
Event: 6.653 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000003340c2c method=java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 16
Event: 6.653 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: reason=bimorphic action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000003340c2c method=java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 16
Event: 6.745 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000346d0cc method=org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.contentsEquals(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Z @ 39
Event: 8.332 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000032952e4 method=java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Ljava/lang/String;I)I @ 1
Event: 8.655 Thread 0x00000000549a4000 Uncommon trap: reason=null_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x000000000349c308 method=java.lang.StringCoding.deref(Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 4
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000327a370 method=java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1.digit(II)I @ 60

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.638 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/log4j/ConsoleAppenderCustomizer> (0x00000005c077d700) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 0.656 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppenderBeanInfo> (0x00000005c07a1748) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 0.656 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/log4j/FileAppenderBeanInfo> (0x00000005c07a3f48) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 0.657 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/log4j/FileAppenderCustomizer> (0x00000005c07a6740) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 0.662 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppenderCustomizer> (0x00000005c07b5bb8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 5.471 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000005c3310cd0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 5.475 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000005c331e390) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 6.600 Thread 0x0000000054a38000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketException': Socket closed> (0x00000005c5801f68) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 8.332 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Implicit null exception at 0x0000000003294db1 to 0x00000000032952d1
Event: 8.655 Thread 0x00000000549a4000 Implicit null exception at 0x000000000349b57d to 0x000000000349c2f9

Events (10 events):
Event: 8.889 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 8.889 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 8.889 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 9.368 loading class java/text/ParsePosition
Event: 9.368 loading class java/text/ParsePosition done
Event: 9.368 loading class java/text/CalendarBuilder
Event: 9.368 loading class java/text/CalendarBuilder done
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000000229f800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x000000000327a370
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000000229f800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x000000000327a370 sp=0x0000000002b6efc0
Event: 9.369 Thread 0x000000000229f800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002e8582a sp=0x0000000002b6ef30 mode 2

0000000055e39d70 000000000327a660
Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f210000 - 0x000000013f247000     C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
0x0000000077b40000 - 0x0000000077cea000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077920000 - 0x0000000077a3f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefdb40000 - 0x000007fefdbaa000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00000000757d0000 - 0x0000000075859000     C:\Windows\System32\SYSFER.DLL
0x000007feffc60000 - 0x000007feffd3b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefe280000 - 0x000007fefe31f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feffd40000 - 0x000007feffd5f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe3b0000 - 0x000007fefe4dd000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077a40000 - 0x0000000077b3a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feffd60000 - 0x000007feffdc7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe320000 - 0x000007fefe32e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feffa60000 - 0x000007feffb2a000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefc3c0000 - 0x000007fefc5b4000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007feffdd0000 - 0x000007feffe41000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefe4e0000 - 0x000007fefe50e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefdf10000 - 0x000007fefe019000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000074400000 - 0x00000000744d2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000062f60000 - 0x00000000637fc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fefad70000 - 0x000007fefad79000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefde60000 - 0x000007fefdead000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe5b0000 - 0x000007fefe5b8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fef74c0000 - 0x000007fef74fb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefcba0000 - 0x000007fefcbac000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000077d10000 - 0x0000000077d17000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000073200000 - 0x000000007320f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000068cc0000 - 0x0000000068ce9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.dll
0x000000006c5e0000 - 0x000000006c5f6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefe5c0000 - 0x000007feff348000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007feff550000 - 0x000007feff753000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefda90000 - 0x000007fefda9f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x0000000069060000 - 0x000000006907a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefd210000 - 0x000007fefd265000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefd670000 - 0x000007fefd677000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefd450000 - 0x000007fefd467000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefcf70000 - 0x000007fefcfb7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefcdb0000 - 0x000007fefcdce000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd980000 - 0x000007fefd98f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefbc90000 - 0x000007fefbcb7000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefbc80000 - 0x000007fefbc8b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefb9f0000 - 0x000007fefba08000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000007fefb9d0000 - 0x000007fefb9e1000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x0000000068ff0000 - 0x0000000069001000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000068c90000 - 0x0000000068cb4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\sunec.dll
0x00000000731f0000 - 0x00000000731fb000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x000007fefdcf0000 - 0x000007fefde57000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefdb30000 - 0x000007fefdb3f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000007fefc730000 - 0x000007fefc745000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fefb250000 - 0x000007fefb265000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fefd0d0000 - 0x000007fefd12b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fefb280000 - 0x000007fefb28b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefcca0000 - 0x000007fefcca7000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefb290000 - 0x000007fefb298000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefbb40000 - 0x000007fefbb93000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x0000000068700000 - 0x00000000687f1000     C:\Windows\Temp\sqlite-3.19.3-c47d36da-90d9-4b67-b5e8-aaf0f27240d2-sqlitejdbc.dll
0x000007fefa760000 - 0x000007fefa885000     C:\Windows\system32\DBGHELP.DLL

VM Arguments:
java_command: H:\jar\App_lite.jar H:\config\Config1.properties
java_class_path (initial): H:\jar\App_lite.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5;C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\AdvDiags\DSET\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\AdvDiags\DSET\bin\Lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\binl;C:\CYGWIN_FINAL_INSTALL\CYGWIN_FINAL_INSTALL\bin;C:\Program Files\010 Editor;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\lib\servlet-api.jar
USERNAME=Administrator
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23677)

CPU:total 32 (initial active 32) (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 100616748k(85759604k free), swap 254214888k(201844688k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Tue Jun 27 11:44:08 2017
elapsed time: 14 seconds (0d 0h 0m 14s)
```

Even though I know problem started coming after installing antivirus but now disabling antivirus is not helping either and I believe code should give graceful error even in case some access issue is there and it should be consistent not an intermittent issue.
 One more thing I suspect could be problematic is that there are multiple processes of the application i.e. many jvm are running same code but with different sqlite file and same jar. It might be possible that the issue is with some conflict of temp files. I tried to use pragma settings of sqlite to change temporary files settings but same problem persists.

Comment: I think this is more of a operating system / virus tool question. So serverfault.com is probably a better place. And for the record: at least for linux, such antivirus solutions hook into the kernel - meaning "just disabling" might be more complicated than you assume.

Comment: Check that your version of sqlite is up-to-date (is not corrupted).

Comment: Check that 1.  Your version of sqlite JAR is up-to-date (is not corrupted).  From looking in mavencentral (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.19.3) version 3.19.3 is the current version.    2.  Check that your sqlite is working correctly (can you do a SQL select via a client).  3.  Check that your Java environment (JVM / JRE) is not corrupted.  4.  I would setup a basic virtual machine (maybe virtual box), and set up a test environment (with fresh Java, sqlite, dependencies), and see if you can run your "SELECT * FROM app_config" code in this clean environment.

Comment: I tried with latest sqlite jar, installing latest version of java. Also select is working fine from 3rd party tools. It is working fine from my code as well most of the time, it just crashes intermittently. @GhostCat thanks for inputs I will post on serverfault as well. I just posted here in hope that someone might be able to pinpoint some problem from pid_err file.

Comment: I am troubled by your comments "it just crashes intermittently"..... "working fine from my code as well most of the time".   You need to set up a clean environment and test the things 1 - 4 in my last comment.

Comment: What unit tests do you have to "exercise your code"?  I suggest you use a tool like Gatling to identify how often "it just crashes intermittently" - on a clean machine.